# Pythonic Boolean Conversion

Tags: python, database, boolean

I'm writing a module to act on data being sent to a database from Python.  Since boolean is not a SQL datatype, those values have to be converted to some pre-defined value.  I decided while defining the tables that I would use 'T' and 'F' in a varchar(1) field as my Boolean stand in.

In attempting to make this conversion while being properly Pythonic, I did a direct comparison and acted on the results, as so:

```
        if SQLParameters[i] == True:
            SQLParameters[i] = 'T'                
        elif SQLParameters[i] == False:
            SQLParameters[i] = 'F'
```

This is on code that runs regardless of type, so if `SQLParameters[i]` is 1 or "Blarg" or 123, I just want to leave it alone, whereas when it's a Boolean, I need to perform the conversion.

This worked just fine until I tried to insert the actual value 1 (one), at which point I learned that `1 == True = True`.  I can plainly see two possible solutions for this issue:

1. change the data dictionary to use 0 and 1 in a number(1) field as the Boolean stand-in, making the conversion simpler
2. add a condition to the code above to check the actual type of the parameter to be converted (which strikes me as unpythonic).

Does anyone have an idea about how to accomplish this without either changing the data dictionary or explicitly checking the type?

Comment: Allan: what database connector are you using that doesn't support boolean conversion ????

Comment: Why are you trying to insert the value '1' into a field where only 'T' and 'F' are valid?  Don't compare against True and False; just say `SQLParameters[i] = True if SQLParameters[i] else False`, so it's always converted.

Comment: Note that Postgresql does have a native Boolean type, and MySQL has a defined convention for booleans (though it's not a real type of its own).

Comment: 'pythonic' is becoming a meaningless buzzword. Avoid it. Using `[i]` everywhere is FORTRANic. Avoid it.

Comment: You don't mention what you wanted to happen when SQLParameters[i] was 1.

Comment: You should use `1` and `0` as the SQL values for True and False.. After all that is what all other SQL databases do when they have boolean column types.. And magically, in Python `1 == True` and `0 == False`.

Comment: @Singularity: I'm using kinterbasdb to connect to Firebird.

Comment: I don't understand your `elif` ... are you doing conversions without any reference to the requirements for the destination SQL column, or is this followed by `else: log_error()`?

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I'm not inserting 1 for a Boolean value.  I'm using the same code for all of the database fields, independent of type.  This works just fine for strings and numeric values, but booleans have, in this circumstance, need some tweaking.

Comment: @Allan: """I'm using the same code for all of the database fields, independent of type. This works just fine""" -- until it doesn't.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder:  If SQLParameters[i] is 1, it is assumed to be a numeric value and is not touched.

Comment: @John Machin:  Well, yes, but that's beyond the scope of this question.  At this time and for my purposes, the implicit conversion is sufficient.  When it's not, I'll revisit that code.

Comment: @Allan : i didn't have time to check all the doc , but are you using this version : http://www.firebirdsql.org/devel/python/docs/3.3.0/index.html because in their title they said __Native Database Engine Features and Extensions Beyond the Python DB API__ so they must support boolean attribute .

Comment: @John Machin:  In this case, whether or not "Pythonic" is generally meaningless, it seemed to suit my purposes in this case, as shorthand for "good practice in Python" (admittedly, not that much shorter).  The i is simply a bad habit that I haven't yet shaken.

Comment: @Singularity: I simply know that when I tried to run the code without the conversion, I got an error (it's been long enough since I tried it that I don't remember the details; it may have just been a check constraint violation).  It's entirely likely this was because the constants I chose to represent True and False were not what it was expecting.

Comment: @Allan: re FORTRANic: the length of the variable name is only a mild part of the problem. Your main problem is the evident array-based thought-pattern.

Comment: @John Machin: My thought patterns are really more set-based, but translating how I would work in SQL to Python tends to lead to headaches, so I fall back to older techniques... However, in terms of the evident array-based problem, is the issue iterating through the array or the use of an array instead of a class?

Comment: @poke: The irony here is that my instinct is to use 0/1, but I went against my nature because some of the Firebird documentation seemed to imply F/T was the preferred convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `is`:

```
if SQLParameters[i] is True:
    SQLParameters[i] = 'T'                
elif SQLParameters[i] is False:
    SQLParameters[i] = 'F'
```

Comment: This best answers the specific question I asked.  However, it seems the consensus viewpoint is that I should change my data dictionary, which would remove the need for the code in question altogether.

Answer (score 3):

```
if isinstance(SQLParameters[i], bool):
    SQLParameters[i] = 'T' if SQLParameters[i] else 'F'
```

or

```
if isinstance(SQLParameters[i], bool):
    SQLParameters[i] = 'FT'[SQLParameters[i]]
```

Comment: +1: Except for the extraneous type-checking, this is golden. :)

Comment: how about `SQLParameters[i] = 'FT'[bool(SQLParameters[i])]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
if SQLParameters[i] is True:
     SQLParameters[i] = 'T'                
elif SQLParameters[i] is False:
     SQLParameters[i] = 'F'
```

"is" captures identities. http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html

True Pythonic (weak datatyping and abbreviated code) would be
SQLParameters[i]  = 'T' if SQLParameters[i] else 'F'

Comment: Wouldn't the second solution fail to capture the identity (which is the source of my issue)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to explicitly test against the identity or value of `SQLParameters[i]` being `True` or `False`.  In Python anything that is unset (such as empty sequences), `None`, `0`, or `False` evaluates to `False`; everything else evaluates to `True`.

So with that in mind you could simply do this:

```
if SQLParameters[i]:
    SQLParameters[i] = 'T'
else:
    SQLParameters[i] = 'F'
```

Comment: This will return set the parameter to 'T' for all non-zero values.  Part of the problem is that the parameter in question may not be a Boolean.

Comment: That is true. I wanted this to be a clear alternative to identity checking.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the object:

```
In [8]: isinstance(True, bool)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: isinstance(1, bool)
Out[9]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend that you use 0 and 1. The SQLite libary does it that way. I would explicitly set the new value to False and then change it to true (or vice versa).

```
convertedvalue = 0
   if SQLParameters[i] is True:
      convertedvalue = 1
SQLParameters[i] = convertedvalue
```